# How to direct user to a login page instead of a login popup in Flask HTTPBasicAuth?

Tags: authentication, flask, forms-authentication, http-authentication

What is the correct way of using HTTPBasicAuth to redirect to a login page? As of now, it always takes me to the `verify_password` function, and I'm shown a popup asking for username and password. Instead, I want it to redirect to a login page and then remember that the user has authenticated successfully via that login page. The official HTTPBasicAuth page does not explain it.

[image]

This is my current code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response, url_for
from flask import render_template
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

#Attribution: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask
#reference: https://github.com/realpython/discover-flask
#Needs: pip install flask-httpauth

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@auth.login_required
def login():
    print('in login')
    print(request.values.get('email'), request.values.get('password'))
    templateToReturn = 'login.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('in post')
        username = request.values.get('email')
        password = request.values.get('password')
        if verify_password(username, password):
            print('password verified')
            templateToReturn = 'index.html'
    print('Curr user', auth.current_user())
    print('request: ', request.method)
    if request.method == 'GET' and auth.current_user():
        templateToReturn = 'index.html'
    return render_template(templateToReturn)

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(email, password):
    print('in verify pwd')
    return verifyAuthentication(email, password)

def verifyAuthentication(email, password):
    knownUsers = {'p1@gmail.com': 'pass', 
                  'p2@yahoo.com': 'pass'}
    authenticated = False
    if email in knownUsers:
        if knownUsers[email] == password:
            authenticated = True
    return authenticated

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    return render_template('logout.html')

@auth.error_handler
def unauthorized():
    return '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div style="text-align: center;">Unauthorized access</div></body></html>'
    
@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_request(error):
    return '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div style="text-align: center;">Bad request</div></body></html>'

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div style="text-align: center;">Page not found</div></body></html>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

and the login form of `login.html`:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('/') }}" method="POST">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" id="login" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-1" style="width:100%;">Login</button>
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: `@auth.login_required` is causing the pop-up, not `if verify_password(username, password):`, which line isn't ran since browsers don't issue POST requests from the url bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a reply from the author of HTTPBasicAuth:

> The library implements a few algorithms from the HTTP standard, most
> importantly the HTTP Basic Authentication protocol. This is not a
> library to create login forms, and normally you would not even use
> login forms with it.
>
> If you want to create a login experience for an application that uses
> HTML, I recommend that you look at the Flask-Login extension, which is
> more appropriate for your use case.